# Can Javascript do polymorphic duck typing for Arrays? (see details)

Tags: javascript

Let's start with some code:

```
function myArray() { }
myArray.prototype = Object.create(Array.prototype);
myArray.prototype.constructor = myArray;
```

So:

```
var myInstance = new myArray();
myInstance.push(1);
>> 1

myInstance.length
>> 1

myInstance instanceof myArray
>> true

myInstance instanceof Array
>> true
```

Everything is standard so far. What I'd like to do is something like:

```
var myNewInstance = myInstance.concat([2,3,4]);
>> [1, 2, 3, 4]
(with the above example it's [{0: 1, length: 1}, 2, 3, 4]

myNewInstance instanceof myArray
>> true
```

I don't know if there's a *right* way to do this ... I can only do it by obtuse wizardry.

I've tried doing things like using `Object.prototype.valueOf` to try to convince the object but that led nowhere.

#### A really convoluted solution

```
myArray.prototype.concat = function() {
  // We start with a new instance of our own object, myArray
  var ret = new myArray();

  // utilize the in-place `splice` to keep the type as `myArray`
  ret.splice.apply(

    // contextualize it for our own object
    ret, 
    Array.prototype.concat.apply( 
      // call it with the start and end of our empty object
      [0, 0],

      // with our object as an array
      Array.prototype.slice.call(this).concat(

        // added to the arguments, as an array
        Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments) 
      )
    ) 
  );

  // since splice returns the stuff that was removed, we
  // need to have an additional line here.
  return ret;
}


var myNewInstance = myInstance.concat([2,3,4]);
>> {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4, length: 4}

myNewInstance instanceof myArray
>> true
```

This does the concat, but it's really hackish - almost like I'm doing it wrong.

Comment: ES6 will allow subclassing Array. It's not possible in today's browsers AFAIK (the order of `myobj.prototype` assignments is incorrect btw).

Comment: ok thanks. I solved it above btw, in a very confusing way.  I wish I could find something more elegant